# Django: how to alter context dictionary based on request method called

Tags: python, django

I am passing a generator object `results` from `fx_rates` view to template like this:

```
def fx_rates(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = FxForm()
        results=[]
    else:
        form = FxForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            scraper = FxScraper()
            scraper.from_currencies.append(form.cleaned_data['from_currencies'])
            scraper.dates = form.cleaned_data['dates'].split(" ")
            scraper.to_currency = form.cleaned_data['to_currency']
            results = scraper.results()

    context = {'form':form, 'results':results}
    return render(request, 'map_assistant/fx_rates.html',context)
```

In the template for this view I am using the below to display results:

```
<ul>     
  {% for result in results %}
    <li>{{result}}</li>
  {% endfor %}        
</ul>
```

(guess I can change it to `{{next(results)}}` once the issue described below is solved).

The problem is I don't know how to prevent "[]" from displaying when the view is called using GET method (see if clause above).

I cannot delete `results=[]` line because I will get an error when the view is called using GET.

Guess I would need to somehow remove results from `context` dictionary when the method is GET?

Answer (score 0):

When the method is GET, try:

```
results = ""
```

This way, results is given a value of empty.

Comment: I can't use this, because then for loop in template won't work (Django will throw an error)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
def fx_rates(request):
    show_div = 'none'
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = FxForm()
        results=[]
    else:
        show_div = 'block'
        form = FxForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            scraper = FxScraper()
            scraper.from_currencies.append(form.cleaned_data['from_currencies'])
            scraper.dates = form.cleaned_data['dates'].split(" ")
            scraper.to_currency = form.cleaned_data['to_currency']
            results = scraper.results()

    context = {'form':form, 'results':results, 'show_div':show_div}
    return render(request, 'map_assistant/fx_rates.html',context)
```

and your html will look like this

```
<div style="display:{{show_div}}">
   <ul>     
  {% for result in results %}
    <li>{{result}}</li>
  {% endfor %}        
</ul>
</div>
```

---

or simply check

```
 {% if result %}
    <ul>     
        {% for result in results %}
    <li>{{result}}</li>
        {% endfor %}        
    </ul>
{% else %}

{% endif %}
```